# Error --accelerator unrecognized argument when launching gcloud beta ai-platform versions create API

Tags: tensorflow, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I would like to deploy my Tensorflow model on a Google AI Platform machine. I already have a working version on a legacy machine **mls1-c4-m2**. Now I would like to make the prediction faster and use a **n1-standard-4** machine with a K80 Nvidia GPU.

I am following this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/machine-types-online-prediction

I have instantiated a model in us-central1, as described in the guide.

This is the command:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $VERSION \
 --model $MODEL \
 --origin $ORIGIN \
 --runtime-version 1.15 \
 --python-version 3.7 \
 --framework tensorflow \
 --machine-type n1-standard-4 \
 --accelerator count=1,type=nvidia-tesla-k80 \
 --config $CONFIG
```

This is the configuration file:

```
runtimeVersion: '1.15'
manualScaling:
  nodes: 1
```

This is the error that I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) unrecognized arguments:
--accelerator
count=1,type=nvidia-tesla-k80
```

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Just tried it on my project and it works fine. Your command looks fine...
From the error it looks like "--accelerator" is on a different line than "count=1,type=nvidia-tesla-k80" Was there a tab or something in there when you ran the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the --accelerator flag is not recognized. 
Maybe you need to upgrade gcloud components